# Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!

Tags: kernel

i'm trying to perform the load command on a clean machine- the process sterted and stuck on this line : `Kernel panic- not syncing: Attempted to kill init!`
what can be the reason?

Comment: What exactly were you doing that lead up to this?  "trying to perform the load command" is too vague to be meaningful.

Comment: @Shira: Were you able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to do a clean install of Ubuntu from CD onto a physical PC?  Do you see any errors that occur leading up to this message?

In any case, that kernel panic message could be caused by a lot of different things.  Often it's hardware related.  I'd suggest running a memory test: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MemoryTest.  You may have bad RAM or just need to reseat it.