# Get a "panic not syncing" message after Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade

Tags: live-usb

I've even created a USB stick to reinstall Ubuntu completely.
But I still get the same message `panic not syncing: attempted to kill init! Exit`

I get this same message when I attempted to reinstall Ubuntu from USB stick. I am thinking Nvidia graphics card may be the problem.

Anyone here have suggestions maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31433/kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init)

Answer (score 0):

Kernel panics happen for a variety of reasons. Often due to hardware failure... You'll need to check out /var/log/dmesg and /var/log/syslog to get more info about what actually happened.

The easier is to use a live OS and re-enable it

```
vim /etc/selinux/config
    ...
    SELINUX=enforcing
    ...
```

Second choise is to disable selinux in the kernel arguments by adding selinux=0

```
vim /boot/grub/grub.conf
    ...
    kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.4.20-selinux-2003040709 ro root=/dev/hda1 nousb selinux=0
    ...
```